# Entering dates in org mode

Tags: org-mode

When I'm capturing an appointment tomorrow at ten, I have
to
write `+ 10:00`.  That seems a bit excessive; is there no
better way?

Comment: `shift-right 10am` will save you 2 keystrokes

Comment: Customize `org-read-date-prefer-future` for defaulting to tomorrow if times earlier than now.

Comment: @Juancho, thanks, this improved my life a bit.  It should be possible, though, to write `10ct` for 'cum tempore', i.e. 10:15.